# What is a semigroup in stochastic analysis?

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, semigroups, semigroup-of-operators

I just read a paper, in which the author wrote

> we use the same notation for the Brownian semigroup on $C_b(\mathbb{R}_{+})$

Apart from this the paper made no other reference to semigroup. I'm wondering what is a semigroup and why we need it in stochastic analysis, is there any good/short introduction to semigroup in stochastic analysis? I have a good grasp on the general theory of stochastic calculus, for example, the content in Bernt Oksendal.

Comment: I am no expert. But Brownian motion is a markov process, and these things in general have semigroups. Google gives https://www.math.unipd.it/~daipra/didattica/Bologna12/MarkovSemgroups-12.pdf which looks useful

Comment: The text **What is a semi-group?** by Einar Hille, which can be found in the book [*Studies in Real and Complex Analysis*](https://books.google.com.br/books?id=4laumAEACAAJ&dq=Studies+in+Real+and+Complex+Analysis+hirschman&hl=pt-BR&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiunqKjss_TAhWFQpAKHQm1BRQQ6AEIIjAA) edited by I. Hirschman, can be of interest.

Answer (score 2):

It is the semi-group of operators in $C_b(\mathbb R_{+})$ defined by $(T_t)f(x)=E(f(B(t)+x))$ where $(B_t)$ is standard Brownian motion.